# windows service WCF does not reache breakpoint of a "Execute"function in _Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Execute));

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF Windows Service, the OnStart function:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); //added for debugging for now
  _Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
  _Host.Open();
  _Manager = new Manager();
  _Manager.Start();
}
```

and  _Manager.Start() calls Agent.Start() which has following definition (pay attention the `Execute`

```
public void Start()
{
  _Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Execute));
  _Thread.Start();
}
```

The parameter `Execute` is a function like following

```
public void Execute()
{
  //mapping data stuff here
  //I put a break point at some line of code in this function
  //but it is not reached
}
```

I put a break point in Execute function code, but even if I press F11 for step in, it just does not go to the `Execute` Function.

It somehow goes into Execute function now, the Execute Function code is like:

```
try
  { System.Messaging.Message amsg = _RequestQueue.Receive();
    /// other code
  }
```

Everytime it passes this line, the debugger is lost...It stays still and doesnot have any other actions, I dont know where it is now...

Great thanks. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few thoughts..

1. Is there any exceptions on _Host.Open()?
2. Are you sure that the thread is created? I mean Thread.Start() is called?

You should be able to attach unless the Execute() function completes it operation before you attach to it.

Edited:

From MSDN, Revive() function Receives the first message available in the queue referenced by the MessageQueue. This call is synchronous, and **blocks the current thread of execution** until a message is available.

Are you sure that the message queue has atleast one message? otherwise the thread will be blocked. If you queue a message, then you can see the debugger becomes alive.

Make sure that you have configured your queue properly.

Comment: @Vivassayi: Hi I have updated the question. could you take a look also please? thanks.